# Yongnuo YN560-TX N + YN-560 IV Flash + YN-568 EX Flash

Tags: off-camera-flash, yongnuo

I have been going through some of the answers here on these two different kind of Yongnuo flashes. I understand YN-568 does not have a wireless receiver built in, as YN-560 has. YN-568 only works as an optical receiver.

My question is, if YN-568 has only an optical receiver, can I trigger it firing the YN-560 through the YN-560TX transmitter mounted on my camera? Does this makes sense?

If this is not doable, if I buy a YongNuo RF-602RX Wireless Flash Receiver for YN-568 will this work?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: An option would be replacing the YN568 with a YN560. Or conversly, replacing the YN560 gear with another YN568. Either would result in a non-hybrid system and that might be worth the <$100 more versus buying triggers.

Answer (score 1):

> ... if YN-568 has only an optical receiver, can I trigger it firing the YN-560 through the YN-560TX transmitter mounted on my camera? Does this makes sense?

You can "daisy-chain" the optical triggering by setting the YN-568EX into S1/S2 mode, and then using the flash burst from the YN-560III/IV to trip it, but this will have all the limitations on range and line-of-sight of optical triggering. And, of course, this type of triggering is manual-only (no TTL/HSS/remote power/zoom control).

> If this is not doable, if I buy a YongNuo RF-602RX Wireless Flash Receiver for YN-568EX will this work?

Yes, but you'd have to put the YN-560 gear into RF-602 mode; it defaults to RF-603 mode.  And the RF-602 units are a pain to use (once you put a flash on top of the receiver, it becomes very hard to reach the on/off switch on the top and the Rx/Tx units *have no locking rings on the feet,* which means putting a flash on top of one can be unstable--especially if you plan on using the passthrough shoe to mount a speedlight on-camera on top of one).

It may be better to get an RF-60**3**II or RF-60**5** transceiver instead of the RF-602-RX. These have the on/off switch on the side, instead of the top and they have locking rings--well worth the extra bump in price. The RF-605 will let you have group on/off control. But neither will let you power-control the YN-568EX.

If you want that, then you'd have to get YN-622 triggers, but then you wouldn't be able to remotely power/zoom-control the YN-560III/IV you have (unless you put the YN-622-TX into Rf-603 mode, at which point you have the same setup as with the YN-560-TX and you can't remotely power/zoom control the 568...). You *could* stack a YN-560-TX/RF-603II/RF-605 on top of a YN-622 receiver, but...

This is why [the Godox system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/) may be better to start out with than Yongnuo if you want to mix manual and TTL/HSS flashes in your set-up and/or advance beyond speedlights to bigger flashes.  I tend to recommend starting out with a TT600 and X1T or XPro transmitter. Only costs a little more than going with a YN-560III/IV/-660 and a YN-560-TX, and if you want to add a TTL/HSS flash to the mix, the TT685 has an X transceiver built in, and the X1T/XPro would give you remote power/HSS control over both flashes, and TTL control over the TT685. Zoom control's more limited than with Yongnuo, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options depending on how much functionality you want/need with the YN-568EX Nikon version.

- You can set the YN-568EX to **S1** mode and let the light from the YN-560 IV trigger it. Of course the YN-568EX will need to be set in *Manual Flash Mode* with all power and zoom settings made directly on the flash. Additionally, the slave sensor in the front of the YN-568EX will need to be able to detect the light from the YN-560 IV. In a dark room this should not be a problem as the light from the YN-560 IV should be able to bounce off walls and trigger the YN-568EX. But if you're in brighter surroundings and using modifiers on your flashes, the burst of light from the YN-560 IV may not be powerful enough.
- You can use any receiver that is compatible with the YN-560TX and attach it to the hot shoe foot of the YN-568EX. This includes the RF-605, RF-603 II, RF-603, and RF-602 as well as the YN-622N II (in RF-603 receiver mode). You'll only be able to fire the flash with the RF-600/RF-602/RF-603/RF-603 II/RF-605 or YN-622N II. This will give you the greater reliability and range of radio compared to optical slave mode. You'll still need to change power/zoom settings directly on the flash, though. If the YN-568EX is buried inside a modifier this could still be a hassle. (The Canon versions allow the YN-560TX to control manual power and zoom wirelessly on Canon E-TTL flashes via a YN-622C II in YN-560TX receiver mode. Unfortunately, the Nikon versions do not.)